# How to prevent pm2 from restarting application on error during startup

Tags: node.js, error-handling, initialization, pm2, process-management

**Context**

I've added configuration validation to some of the modules that compose my Node.js application. When they are starting, each one checks if it is properly configured and have access to the resources it needs (e.g. can write to a directory). If it detects that something is wrong it sends a SIGINT to itself (process.pid) so the application is gracefully shutdown (I close the http server, close possible connections to Redis and so on). I want the operator to realize there is a configuration and/or environment problem and fix it before starting the application.

I use pm2 to start/stop/reload the application and I like the fact pm2 will automatically restart it in case it crashes later on, but I don't want it to restart my application in the above scenario because the root cause won't be eliminated by simply restarting the app, so pm2 will keep restarting it up to `max_restarts` (defaults to 10 in pm2).

**Question**

How can I prevent pm2 from keeping restarting my application when it is aborted during startup?

I know pm2 has the `--wait-ready` option, but given we are talking about multiple modules with asynchronous startup logic, I find very hard to determine where/when to `process.send('ready')`.

**Possible solution**

I'm considering making all my modules to emit an internal "ready" event and wire the whole thing chaining the "ready" events to finally be able to send the "ready" to pm2, but I would like to ask first if that would be a little bit of over engineering.

Thanks,

Roger